# 'NoneType is not iterable' with datetime objects

Tags: python, parsing, rss, timestamp

When I run this codes I get the following error message.

> "error:in parseres, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import feedparser

content = {}
content2= {}
content3= {}
source = ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/", "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss" )

for i in source:
    content = feedparser.parse(i)
    for feed in content.entries:
        content2[feed.title] = [feed.published]

content3 = [(item[0], parser.parse(item[1])) for item in content2]
print content3
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amirnakhostin/Documents/Computer Science /Python/HomeStudy.py", line 13, in <module>
    content3 = [(item[0], parser.parse(item[1])) for item in content2]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 748, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 310, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback including line number?

Comment: Are you aware that `for item in content2` loops over the keys of `content2`, not key-value pairs? I don't see you using the values of `content2` anywhere. Also, you don't need to "declare" the `content` and `content3` variables, especially since you're not using them to hold dicts.

Comment: What is feedparser? Is it your own class? Obviously the exception happens in a private method named _parse. I'm sure it is in the feedparser and somthing is wrong there or you use it the wrong way. But there is not enough information to say more about.

Comment: @this.myself: feedparser is a library. I'm not sure what it does exactly, except I guess it parses web feeds. His problem is related to what user2357112 said. For more information you can look at my answer.

Comment: @anon Let give it a shot I think you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what happens when you run a slightly modified program of this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import feedparser

content = {}
content2= {}
content3= {}
source = ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/", "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss" )

for i in source:
    content = feedparser.parse(i)
    for feed in content.entries:
        content2[feed.title] = [feed.published]

print content2

content3 = [(item[0], parser.parse(item[1])) for item in content2]
print content3
```

You get:

```
[(u'B', u'o'), (u'B', u'l'), (u'W', u'h'), (u'W', u'o'), (u'U', u'S'), (u'M', u'o'), (u'T', u'i'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'7', u'0'), (u'G', u'o'), (u'H', u'i'), (u'I', u's'), (u'M', u'e'), (u'T', u'h'), (u'B', u'e'), (u'W', u'a'), (u'O', u'f'), (u'V', u'i'), (u'C', u'h'), (u'S', u't'), (u'F', u'a'), (u'L', u'e'), (u'S', u'u'), (u'B', u'e'), (u'P', u's'), (u'A', u'P'), (u'S', u't'), (u'M', u'i'), (u'I', u'c'), (u'F', u'a'), (u"'", u'D'), (u'E', u'P'), (u'M', u'a'), (u"'", u'G'), (u'C', u'l'), (u'L', u'a'), (u'8', u' '), (u'S', u'e'), (u'C', u'h'), (u'9', u' '), (u'A', u'n'), (u'A', u' '), (u'C', u'a'), (u'O', u'f'), (u'6', u' '), (u'C', u'h'), (u'1', u'9'), (u'W', u'a'), (u'T', u'h'), (u'G', u'o'), (u"'", u'T'), (u'L', u'o'), (u'M', u'a'), (u'D', u'o'), (u'U', u'.'), (u'P', u'o'), (u'I', u'd'), (u"'", u'B'), (u'C', u'h'), (u'U', u'S'), (u'D', u'i'), (u'E', u'x'), (u'I', u' '), (u'F', u'o'), (u'T', u'h'), (u'D', u'i'), (u'E', u'n'), (u'T', u'e'), (u'B', u'r'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'M', u'o'), (u"'", u'H'), (u'W', u'o'), (u'M', u'u'), (u'5', u'3'), (u'M', u'a'), (u'W', u'e'), (u'W', u'h'), (u'A', u'r'), (u'E', u'a'), (u'B', u'e'), (u'F', u'i'), (u'I', u'n'), (u'G', u'r'), (u'U', u'.'), (u'S', u'e'), (u'T', u'h'), (u'M', u'i'), (u'W', u'h'), (u'C', u'h'), (u'S', u'p'), (u'F', u'r'), (u'T', u'i'), (u'A', u'c'), (u"'", u'B'), (u'2', u'0'), (u'H', u'a'), (u'G', u'l'), (u'W', u'h'), (u'M', u'u'), (u'C', u'N'), (u'B', u'e'), (u'A', u'r'), (u'M', u'o'), (u'K', u'i'), (u'T', u'u'), (u'D', u'o'), (u'A', u'm'), (u'A', u' '), (u'D', u'e'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'W', u'h'), (u'W', u'i'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'$', u'2'), (u'Y', u'o'), (u'5', u'3'), (u'S', u't'), (u'S', u'c'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'P', u'r'), (u'V', u'o'), (u'M', u'e'), (u'V', u'.'), (u'M', u'a'), (u"'", u'G'), (u'L', u'o'), (u'F', u'r'), (u'H', u'o'), (u'M', u'e'), (u'E', u'c'), (u"'", u'B'), (u'S', u'.'), (u'T', u'h'), (u'G', u'l'), (u'A', u'P'), (u'A', u'm'), (u'R', u'u'), (u'M', u'a'), (u'T', u'e'), (u'G', u'i'), (u'I', u's'), (u'P', u'h'), (u'O', u'f'), (u'M', u'i'), (u'B', u'o'), (u'C', u'h'), (u'R', u'e'), (u'W', u'o'), (u'R', u'i')]
```

Look at the first entry in your `content2`:

```
{u'Bowe Bergdahl': [u'Sun, 01 Jun 2014 17:02:05 EDT']
```

Instead you probably want:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import feedparser

content = {}
content2= {}
content3= {}
source = ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/", "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss" )

for i in source:
    content = feedparser.parse(i)
    for feed in content.entries:
        content2[feed.title] = [feed.published]

print content2

content3 = [(key, parser.parse(val[0])) for (key,val) in content2.iteritems()]
print content3
```

This gives:

```
[(u'Bowe Bergdahl', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 17, 2, 5)), (u'Blast kills 18 in Nigeria', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 20, 16, 8)), (u'Who did U.S. swap Bergdahl for?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 22, 51, 43)), (u'World Cup forces out drug gangs', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 22, 5, 38)), (u'US defends captive swap with Taliban, critics stir', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 56, 50, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Model fights Google over porn photos', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 23, 27, 49)), (u'Hong Kong rallies for democracy', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 23, 28, 51)), (u"70 years after D-Day, she hears dad's stories anew", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 15, 36, 9, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"Go inside Brazil's war on drugs", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 23, 10)), (u'Hiroshima bomb site draws crowds', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 22, 44, 37)), (u'Is Mideast the new global aviation hub?', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 14, 21, 18)), (u'Meteors streak through night sky', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 7, 11, 11)), (u'Thumbs up', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 8, 27, 41)), (u"Bergdahl's parents: 'It isn't over'", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 1, 53, 21)), (u'Walter White and the undead', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 49, 15)), (u'Officials: 7 aboard NJ-bound plane die in crash', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 3, 54, 1, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Visionary concept cars', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 7, 13, 7)), (u'Chinese hackers infiltrated U.S.', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 19, 23, 0, 51)), (u'Store defends flag likened to KKK hood', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 22, 0, 19)), (u"Family 'wanted $1000 not to kill wife'", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 11, 35, 1)), (u'Learning to talk with autism', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 30, 9, 41, 40)), (u'Suspect in Jewish museum killings went to Syria', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 18, 46, 2, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"Bergdahl's mother: 'It's a good day'", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 9, 2, 23)), (u'Psychopaths: Better in business?', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 12, 52, 58)), (u'AP PHOTOS: Iran mineral baths offer relief', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 21, 41, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Sterling sues NBA for $1B', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 23, 33, 50)), (u"Miley Cyrus' home robbed, police say", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 19, 34, 34)), (u"Iceland's awesome Westfjords", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 14, 23, 1)), (u"Family's plea: Hang rapists", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 8)), (u"'Drug dealers' of the sticker world", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 45, 58)), (u'EPA seeks to cut power plant carbon by 30 percent', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 4, 37, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Mastering cyber-espionage', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 25, 14)), (u"'Gangnam' hits 2 billion YouTube views", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 32, 39)), (u'Clues sought in deadly Massachusetts jet crash', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 34, 22, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Lack of empathy a bonus', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 12, 53, 47)), (u'8 charged over Tiananmen attack', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 1, 26, 51)), (u'Secret eyes watching you shop', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 7, 33, 31)), (u'China, Vietnam tensions rise', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 1, 26, 31)), (u'9 most controversial foods', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 1, 39, 28)), (u"Andy Warhol's lost art", datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 11, 11, 30)), (u'A one of a kind friendship', datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 21, 8, 18, 8)), (u'Campaigner quits after expose', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 7, 9, 28)), (u'Official: Recovering fallen climbers too dangerous', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 20, 25, 34, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'6 climbers missing on U.S. mountain', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 31, 52)), (u"Chuck Hagel: Captive's life was in danger", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 5, 26, 4, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Was caste to blame?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 29, 23)), (u"Thai protesters come out again despite junta's ban", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 8, 17, 23, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"Google's car is the 'future'", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 22, 39)), (u"'Too sexy' yearbook photos edited?", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 13, 26, 44)), (u'Long road to recovery for POWs', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 5, 21)), (u'Man arrested over museum attack', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 21, 6, 15)), (u'Tackling sanitation', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 33, 43)), (u'Doh! 20 biggest travel mistakes', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 5, 22, 36)), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 23, 2, 30, 44)), (u"Poll: More Americans oppose Snowden's actions", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 18, 41, 50, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Idaho town prepares for homecoming', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 9, 2, 23)), (u"'Brady Bunch' star Ann B. Davis dies", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 21, 43, 58)), (u'China, Vietnam face off in S. China Sea', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 23, 54, 48)), (u'US soldier freed from captivity in Afghanistan', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 22, 40, 7, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Did sex traffic hero invent story?', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 12, 52, 14)), (u'Extremists busted in Xinjiang', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 1, 23, 59)), (u"I was an accomplice to my brother's suicide", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 11, 21, 48)), (u'Former NYC Mayor Bloomberg calls for stricter gun laws', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 53, 29, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"The world's most incredible origami", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 26, 35)), (u'Did Qatar buy 2012 World Cup?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 5, 23)), (u"Enter into Congo's cult of elegance", datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 5, 43, 59)), (u'Teen attempts record solo RTW flight', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 36, 44)), (u'Brothers confess to gang rape in India', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 1, 55, 3)), (u'How to train like a top cyclist', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 46, 52)), (u'Mothers reveal how to raise a winner', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 42, 42)), (u"'Horse quidditch' seeks Olympic spot", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 20, 46)), (u"World Cup's most exotic city awaits tourist influx", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 8, 38, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Museum shooting', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 9, 23)), (u'53 spectacular wildlife photos', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 6, 18, 5)), (u'Maya Angelou film set for release', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 58, 32)), (u'We need birds, and birds need us', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 7, 33, 42)), (u'What does sentence say about Sudan?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 37, 24)), (u'Are old cellphones a new fad?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 43, 28)), (u'Easy for Rafa, Murray on brink', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 22, 0, 52)), (u'Best wildlife trips in the U.S.', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 11, 36, 7)), (u'Fisherman reels in rare saw shark', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 22, 54)), (u'India gang rape', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 20, 53, 33)), (u"Grief and fear in girls' village", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 21, 12, 22)), (u'U.S. soldier freed in Afghanistan, 5 Taliban prisoners leave Gitmo', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 59, 6, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Sex trafficking hero quits after expose', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 10, 41, 3)), (u'The shocking truth about tobacco', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 23, 53, 48)), (u'Mickelson denies fraud allegations', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 21, 53, 35)), (u"What are 'firenadoes'?", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 16, 13, 38, 44)), (u"China's blind head to exam hall", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 19, 23, 1, 14)), (u'Spelling Bee crowns two W-I-N-N-E-R-S', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 28, 47)), (u'From humble GIF to high art', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 17, 12, 37, 32)), (u'Tiananmen Square attack: 8 charged', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 12, 19, 11)), (u'Accused Brad Pitt attacker fired', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 16, 27)), (u"'Brady Bunch' actress Ann B. Davis dies in Texas", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 1, 3, 20, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'20 biggest travel mistakes', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 1, 37, 20)), (u'Hackers use social media to spy', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 3, 4, 33)), (u'Glamorous Orient Express', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 30, 11, 50, 43)), (u"Where is S. Korea's most wanted man?", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 33, 47)), (u'Museum gunman caught on video', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 14, 25)), (u'CNN reporter held by police on air', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 18, 33)), (u'Bergdahl taken to German hospital', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 6, 57)), (u'Are you a psychopath? Take the test', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 12, 50, 1)), (u'Most controversial foods', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 14, 23, 39)), (u'Kings beat Blackhawks 5-4 in OT in Game 7', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 51, 40, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Turkish cops harass CNN reporter', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 23, 30, 43)), (u'Do wearable fitness gadgets work?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 24, 52)), (u'Americans fighting for al Qaeda', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 9, 5)), (u'A billion dollar artwork?', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 14, 7, 4, 17)), (u'Death sentence for tycoon', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 23, 2, 30, 27)), (u'How to buy a great watch', datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 31, 13, 40, 44)), (u'Why superheroes are good for kids', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 29, 11, 15, 43)), (u'Will monks ban interfaith marriage?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 2, 33, 1)), (u"How to win China's tourists", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 1, 30, 48)), (u"$2B for the Clippers? You're kidding", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 20, 36, 5)), (u"You're never too young to be CEO", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 19, 11, 7, 18)), (u'53 spectacular wildlife shots', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 6, 14, 3)), (u'Sterling sues NBA for $1 billion', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 2, 10)), (u'Scenes from the field', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 6, 3, 12, 27)), (u'Private plane crash kills 7 in U.S.', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 20, 17, 28)), (u'Volcano grounds flights in Asia', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 35, 52)), (u"Meet India's next PM", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 16, 13, 38, 32)), (u'V. Stiviano assaulted in New York', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 1, 24, 46)), (u'Man catches baby after fall', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 1, 28, 57)), (u"'Gangnam' milestone", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 32, 39)), (u"Look, no driver: Google's new car", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 13, 29, 27)), (u'Without toilets, women are vulnerable', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 29, 42)), (u"France: Suspect in Brussels' Jewish Museum shooting arrested", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 7, 27, 59, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'How to make cash from trash', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 6, 18, 53)), (u'Meet the armless table tennis champ', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 15, 39, 40)), (u"Eco wonders from 'shabby' mines", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 19, 23, 1, 56)), (u"'Brady Brunch' actress Ann B. Davis dies in Texas", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 20, 4, 59, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'S. Korean sentenced in North Korea', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 2, 33, 5)), (u"The world's top furniture fair", datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 14, 7, 2, 53)), (u'Glass floor cracks under tourists', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 17, 7)), (u'AP PHOTOS: Teams, fans counting down to World Cup', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 2, 31, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'American suicide bomber in Syria?', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 17, 58)), (u'Russian proton rocket fails', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 16, 13, 33, 53)), (u'Mastery of Easter eggs', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 24, 7, 32, 38)), (u'Terror arrest at Heathrow Airport', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 22, 0, 20)), (u'Gitmo detainees', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 51, 7)), (u"Is this the return of 'White Plague'?", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 2, 47, 9)), (u'Philadelphia Inquirer co-owner dead in plane crash', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 9, 54, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Official: 6 climbers likely died in mountain fall', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 14, 27, 5, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"Mickelson: I've done nothing wrong", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 22, 6, 32)), (u'Bowe Bergdahl: Hero or deserter?', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 1, 48, 9)), (u'China faces war on terror', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 25, 22, 35, 52)), (u'Report: NSA collects facial images', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 21, 9, 15)), (u"World's 10 most underrated cities", datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 11, 19, 23)), (u'Rise of the mega-museums', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10, 15, 51, 38))]
```

Or maybe you want to keep it a dict?

Comment: one last question. what if I wanted to sort "content" based on content.published?

Comment: Sorry man, I don't know feedparser well enough to help with that, try asking that as a separate question, or look into the feedparser documentation, or something.